# Instantiating an object who's type depends on another object's type

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns

As a part of my model I have a class called "Slide" which has two children : "QuizzSlide" and "ImageSlide". I also have another class called "SlideView" (which is part of my views) which has two children "QuizzSlideView" and "ImageSlideView".

Now what I want to do is go through a collection of Slides and create the correct SlideViews to display them. Problem is, to instantiate a SlideView I need to know the type of the Slide. QuizzSlide should create a QuizzSlideView and ImageSlide should create an ImageSlideView. I see two options :

1. Introspection. I don't like introspection because it means the class that builds the object has to exhaustively list the types of objects that it can deal with. If I add another type of Slides down the line, I have to modify the builder class.
2. Making the Slide create its associated View. So I'd have a function getView that gets overridden by every child of Slide to create the correct View for that slide. This would work and it would make maintenance easier but it makes a horrible mess of the program as the model shouldn't contain references to the views it represents.

That's pretty much it. Do I have any other options? Any ideas on how to uncouple my models from my views, build the correct views depending on the model types AND avoid introspection?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the complication (perhaps I am missing something).  In the controller isn't it a case of `if ([slideInstance isKindOfClass:[QuizzSlide class]]) { view = [[QuizzView alloc] initWithFrame...]; } else if ( ... ) { ... }`?

Comment: If I wanted to use introspection yes. But that would mean that for every slide type I add later on I'll have to go back to that controller and add another "isKindOfClass", furthermore any operation I want to do on those Slide classes collectively would need an "isKindOfClass". I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) `createView()` in the `Slide` class which, when implemented in `QuizzSlide` returns a `QuizzSlideView` and in `ImageSlide` returns an `ImageSlideView` pointing to the proper model.

This reminds me of the [Iterator](http://www.silversoft.net/docs/dp/hires/pat5dfso.htm) pattern, where `CreateIterator()` is the factory method.

[Iterator pattern in UML http://www.silversoft.net/docs/dp/hires/Pictures/itera040.gif](http://www.silversoft.net/docs/dp/hires/Pictures/itera040.gif)

Comment: Yeah that's the second option I talked about, the only issue with this solution is that I'm tying my models to my views. Which is bad in general but especially bad in my case because the models and views have different life cycles. Wait, unless you mean the slides should just create the object without holding a reference? Hmmm... this could actually work! I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: Why should Model elements not know their Views? It's because views are assumed to be less stable with respect to their models, and you want to avoid change propagation into the models unnecessarily. The "horrible mess" you mention. If you think that views change too much, you could inject your Views into Slides when you instantiate them. But it seems like another mess, like introspection. The relationship of one View per Slide is probably stable, much like that of the Iterator example. You can choose your battles (messes) and accept the risk of a model knowing its view.

Answer (score 1):

I think the introspection method is best, however if you are concerned about having to modify the code if you introduce new classes (a legitimate concern) then I would make it *table driven*, which would limit the amount of new code required.

(Note I have not tested this code):

```
static struct {
    Class slideClass;
    Class viewClass;
} _slideMap[] = {
    { [QuizzSlide class], [QuizzView class] },
    { [ImageSlide class], [ImageView class] }
};
#define NUM_SLIDE_MAPS (sizeof(_slideMap) / sizeof(_slideMap[0]))
```

Then use:

```
for (id slide in _slides) {
    UIView *view = nil;
    CGRect frame = ...;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < NUM_SLIDE_MAPS && !view; i++)
        if ([slide isKindofClass:_slideMap[i].slideClass])
            view = [[_slideMap[i].viewClass alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    NSAssert(view, @"Missing slide/view map entry for class %@", NSStringFromClass([slide class]));
}
```

Note: It's possible this code won't compile as the expression `[QuizzSlide class]` is not a constant expression, in which case you will be forced to create the array at runtime, using a `dispatch_once()` statement or some such.

You might also be able to use an `NSDictionary` to hold the mapping between the slide and view classes and get even quicker look-up performance.

Comment: Thanks. This is a reasonable fix for the introspection issue and I might go with this. I stumbled upon the visitor pattern while looking at a solution on my end though, and I'm still trying to see if it solves my problem in an elegant way.